# Trying to print a subclass method in a main class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes. An abstract class, a derived class and a main class. I am trying to print the method in the derived class in the main class.

```
public abstract class newsPaperSub {
    public String name;
    public abstract void address();
    public double rate;
}
```

Derived class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhysicalNewspaperSubscription extends newsPaperSub {
    @Override
    public void address () {
        String subAddress = " ";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        int digitCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < subAddress.length(); i++) {
            char c = subAddress.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                digitCount++;
                System.out.println("Pease enter an address: ");
                 subAddress = input.nextLine();
                if (digitCount <= 1) {
                    rate = 15;
                    System.out.println("Your subscrption price is: " + rate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main class: I havent been able to figure out what to exactly put in the main class in order to print the function in the derived class. I have tried a couple things with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class demo {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment you haven't tried to put any `newsPaperSub` into `main` at all...

Comment: you may want to create an object of type `newsPaperSub`, instantiate it with the instance of `PhysicalNewspaperSubscription` (`new PhysicalNewspaperSubscription()` ) and call the method using the object.

Answer (score 0):

Just put inside of the main method

```
PhysicalNewspaperSubscription subscription= new PhysicalNewspaperSubscription()
```

and then call your method

```
subscription.address()
```

in the main method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
public class demo {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    PhysicalNewspaperSubscription pns = new PhysicalNewspaperSubscription();
    pns.address();
  }
}
```

... but your code will not do anything.

The reason being because though you have a `Scanner` to read in something from the console, it'll never run that piece of code because the following loop structure never runs:

```
for (i = 0; i < subAddress.length(); i++) {
   ...
}
```

The reason it does not run is because when you declare `subAddress` you set it to an empty `String` (`String subAddress = " ";`), so when the loop checks the condition (`i < subAddress.length()`) it'll evaluate `FALSE`, because 0 < 0 is `FALSE` and hence not run the loop.

Comment: @MattGage, did this answer your question? If so, please mark it as resolved. Tx.